# My generated ASP.NET Button doesn't actually do anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls

Right now I've got a method that's dynamically generating a table of information based on input in a search bar, with a button located on each row. When pressed, that button is supposed to take the information present in its row and process it.

My problem is that my buttons aren't doing anything, but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. Even trying to post to the output panel in VS doesn't work. As soon as I press one, all it does is wipe out all of my values - everything in my table - all back to default by refreshing the page.

```
    // The bottom section of the method which 'generates' buttons for each row made in the for loop - everything works perfect to this point

    TableCell addButtonCell = new TableCell();
    Button addButton = new Button();
    addButton.Text = "Add";
    addButton.Width = 75;
    addButton.Click += new EventHandler(addButton_Click);

    addButtonCell.Controls.Add(addButton);
    row.Cells.Add(addButtonCell);

    tblResults.Rows.Add(row);
}

// button event handler
public void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("TESTING!!!!!"); // Tried this, no effect
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? If your page is refreshing i believe your button is workign as expected. Plus the process you in the click event will all shown within the ouput window of VS.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to prevent it from reloading the page but still execute the code then, is there? I've attempted to do other things with the handler - but of course, it's refreshing, so it's wiped anyways.

Comment: use update panel to avoid refresh.

Comment: did you find answer?

Comment: I did not. Unfortunately none of the solutions proposed worked in my case, so I had to change around the design instead - but I got it to work for that new design.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever controls are created Dynamically, needs to be created each time the page loaded.

SOLUTION:

You need to do the way I done in the following...

```
    TableRow row;
    TableCell cell;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ReloadDynamicControls();
        }
        else
        {
            DynamicControls = new List<Button>();
        }
    }
    private void ReloadDynamicControls()
    {
        if (this.DynamicControls != null)
        {
            foreach (Button button in DynamicControls)
            {
                button.Click += new EventHandler(btnKill_Click);
                row = new TableRow();
                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(button);
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Button> DynamicControls
    {
        get { return Session["DynamicControls"] != null ? (List<Button>)Session["DynamicControls"] : null; }
        set { Session["DynamicControls"] = value; }
    }
```

And you need change you generate button method with this code:

```
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        tblResults.Controls.Add(tr);
        Button addButton = new Button();
        addButtonCell = new TableCell();
        addButtonCell.Controls.Add(addButton);
        tr.Controls.Add(addButtonCell);
        addButton.Width = 75;
        addButton.Text = "Add";
        addButton.ID = "btn_" + this.DynamicControls.Count.ToString();
        addButton.Click += new EventHandler(addButton_Click);
        addButton.EnableViewState = true;
        DynamicControls.Add(addButton);

        tr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
        tblResults.Rows.Add(tr);
```

The original solution [here](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/390163/How-to-create-dynamic-buttons-on-click-of-dynamic-button-in-ASPNet/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd wanna include here that the query should have a WHERE clause and should be limitted by 1, ensuring that actually one result is returned. then the if should also be changed to if($result->num_rows == 0).